# How can I select any <a> tag on my page to assign it a class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a board of tiles which are `<a>` tags for a game.
They each have an id based on their x/y grid values and I have assigned some images to them by using jQuery to select specific id's and then adding classes to put images onto these.

However, I would like to select a random `<a>` tag to add the class to rather than a specific id, how could I do that using jQuery?

```js
$("#tile0-0").addClass("Jim")
$("#tile2-2").addClass("crystal")
$("#tile5-1").addClass("snowman")
$("#tile6-9").addClass("snowman")
$("#tile2-5").addClass("snowman")
$("#tile3-3").addClass("snowballs")
$("#tile9-1").addClass("tree")
$("#tile4-7").addClass("gun")
```

Comment: Store the tags in an array, then pick a random tag from it, turn it into a jquery object and then add class to it.

Comment: Or just store an array of ID's and select randomly from that.

Comment: Or give each tag the same class like `.title`, and get a random tag using a random index value.

Comment: Any of the above will work. If you want a specific answer, please add the relevant HTML and your attempt to solve this in JS to the question

Comment: Don't use multiple IDs with in the page.Its the bad practice

Comment: Thanks guys! I appreciate the input!

Answer (score 2):

You can select all `a` tags with `tile...` IDs, then choose a random element from that list and add the class:

```js
function addClassToRandomTile(classname) {
  const tiles = document.querySelectorAll('a[id^="tile"]');
  const choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * tiles.length);
  tiles[choice].classList.add(classname);  
}

addClassToRandomTile('Jim');
```

```css
.Jim {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a id=tile0-0>0-0</a>
<a id=tile2-2>2-2</a>
<a id=tile5-1>5-1</a>
```

Or the equivalent jQuery:

```js
function addClassToRandomTile(classname) {
  const tiles = $('a[id^="tile"]');
  const choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * tiles.length);

  $(tiles[choice]).addClass(classname);
}

addClassToRandomTile('Jim');
```

```css
.Jim {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id=tile0-0>0-0</a>
<a id=tile2-2>2-2</a>
<a id=tile5-1>5-1</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, I might try that out. Seems like a nice way to add my components.

Answer (score 2):

The function flow should be,
1. Get all the elements which have ID starts with "title"
2. Pick a random element from the list
3. Add class to that randomly picked element.

```
function addRandomClass(className) {
  var elems = $("a[id^='tile']"); /*Select all elements which have ID starts with 'tile'*/
  var randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length); /*Pick a random number between 0 and (no of elements -1)*/
  elems[randomValue].addClass(className);/*Add Class to the selected random element*/
}
```

The above function can be used as

```
addRandomClass("spec-elem"); /*class 'spec-elem' will be added to the random element */
```

Answer (score 1):

The skeleton would be

```
var obj = $("#title0-0, #title2-2, ...");
var elem = $(obj.get(randomElementIndex)).addClass('foo');
```

You could also decide to give all of the elements you want to select from in randomizing a common classs, and then just do

```
var obj = $(".myCommonTileClass");
```

Comment: Thanks!
I ended up using this in the end:
             
$.fn.random = function() {
  return this.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length));
}          

$(selector).random();

Comment: But I may well revise try it the way you suggested as it seems like a good way to avoid repeating code.Thanks!